# Array of data failed to save into the dababase using Laravel

Tags: laravel

In Laravel-5.8 project, I have these models:

```
class Rating extends Model
 {
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'ratings';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
                  'rating_description',
                  'rating_value',
              ];

 }

class Skill extends Model
{

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'skills';
    protected $fillable = [
                  'skill_name',
              ];

}

class EmployeeRating extends Model
{
   public $timestamps = false;
   protected $table = 'employee_ratings';

   protected $primaryKey = 'id';

   protected $fillable = [
                'employee_id',  
                'skill_id',
                'rating_id',
                'comment',
            ];
  
  
   protected $casts = [
    'data' => 'array',
   ];

  public function employees()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Employee');
  } 
  
  public function skills()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Skill', 'skill_id', 'id' );
  }     

  public function ratings()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Rating', 'rating_id', 'id' );
  } 

}
```

Rules Request

```
class StoreEmployeeRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return \Gate::allows('employee_rating_create');
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [   
                    
            'skill_id'           => 'required|array',
            'skill_id.*' => [
                 'required',         

            'rating_id'           => 'required|array', 
            'rating_id.*' => [
                 'required',  
                              
            ],                     
           
            'comment'           => 'nullable|array',
            'comment.*' => [
                 'nullable', 
             
            ],         
        ];
    }

    public function attributes()
    {
        return  [
            'skill_id.*'              => 'Appraisal Skill',
            'rating_id.*'  => 'Rating',
            'comment.*'                          => 'Comment',
        ];
    }                   
}
```

EmployeeRating is the main model. An employee has several ratings using skills.

I iterate using skill

Controller

```
public function creat($id)
{
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;
    $employee = Employee::where('id', $id)->first();
    $skills = Skill::where('company_id', $userCompany)->get();
    $ratings = Rating::where('company_id', $userCompany)->get(); 
    $count_ratings = Rating::where('company_id', $respondent->company_id)->get()->count(); 
    return view('employee_ratings.create')
            ->with('skills', $skills)
            ->with('ratings', $ratings)
            ->with('count_ratings', $count_ratings)
            ->with('employee', $employee);
}   

public function store(StoreEmployeeRequest $request,$id)
{
        foreach ($request->skill_id as $key => $skill_id){

    $insert_array = [
            'skill_id'                        => $request->appraisal_skill_id[$key],
            'rating_id'                    => $request->rating_id[$key],
            'comment'                                   => $request->comment[$key],
        ];
     EmployeeRating::create($insert_array );
 }
```

All the data should be inserted into EmployeeRating.

The form looks like this:

[![employee rating][1]][1]

view

```
<form  action="{{route('appraisal.employee_ratings.store', ['id'=>$respondent->id])}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       {{csrf_field()}}
 <input type="hidden" name="count_ratings_no" value="{{$count_ratings}}">
   <table id="msfTable" class=" table table-bordered table-striped table-hover datatable">
        <thead>
           <tr>
              <th scope="col" width="4%">ID</th>
              <th scope="col" width="25%">Core Value<span style="color:red;">*</span></th>                                    
              <th scope="col" class="text-center" width="25%" colspan="{{$count_ratings}}">Rating<span style="color:red;">*</span></th>                                                                    
              <th scope="col" width="46%">Comment</th>
                  </tr>
               </thead> 
               <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col" width="4%"></th>
                    <th scope="col" width="25%"></th>                                    
                       @foreach($ratings as $rating)
                    <th scope="col" width="25%">
                        {{$rating->rating_description}}
                      </th>
                     @endforeach                                                                                                         
                        <th scope="col" width="46%"></th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>                             
              <tbody>
                @foreach ($skills as $key => $skill)
                  <tr>
                    <td width="4%">
                       {{$key+1}}
                   </td>
                  <td width="25%">
                   <span>{{$skill->skill_name}}</span>                                     
                </td>                                    
                                @foreach($ratings as $index => $rating)
                    <td><input type="radio" name="skill[{{ $key}}]rating" id="{!! $rating->id !!}" @if (!$index) {!! "checked" !!} @endif required></td>
                                @endforeach                                                                       
                    <td width="46%">    
                       <input type="text" name="comment[]" placeholder="Enter comment here" class="form-control comment">
                     </td>                                      
                </tr>
            @endforeach
      </tbody>
  </table>
 </form>
```

When I submitted, I got this error:

```
 skill_id field is required
 rating_id field is required
```

Yet the fields are not empty, but no data is inserted into the database.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: where is your form .? can't see how it submited

Comment: @KamleshPaul- I've added the form. So sorry about that.

Comment: @user11352561 paste the code for StoreEmployeeRequest  file

Comment: @KhalidKhan - I have updated the code with StoreEmployeeRequest

Comment: @user11352561 check my below answer and update your file like it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Radio button HTML part with this

```
@foreach($ratings as $index => $rating)
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="rating_{{$key}}" value="{{$rating->id}}" id="{!! $rating->id !!}" @if (!$index) {!! "checked" !!} @endif required>
    </td>
@endforeach
```

And in your controller do the dd like this to find out what you are getting into `$request` variable from HTML form

```
public function store(StoreEmployeeRequest $request,$id){
    dd($request->all());
    foreach ($request->skill_id as $key => $skill_id){
        $insert_array = [
            'skill_id' => $request->appraisal_skill_id[$key],
            'rating_id' => $request->rating_id[$key],
            'comment' => $request->comment[$key],
        ];
        EmployeeRating::create($insert_array);
    }
 }
```

Let me know if you face any problem

Comment: When I did that, the error is no more there, but it didn't save anything into the Database. I think the issue is from the view and controller. Especially the view. What will it save for thoss two fields (skill_id and rating_id)

Comment: Can you show me your migration of the related table

Comment: The Models (tables) are there at the beginning of the post.  employee_ratings is the main table and it has foreign key: rating_id from ratings and skill_id from skills

Comment: @user11352561 Actually you haven't given name to any HTML field as rating_id or skill_id and moreover you are even accessing the objects which are not even there in your form code. That's probably is causing the error

Comment: How do I transfer this skill[{{ $key}}]rating from view blade to the controller as in  'rating_id'  => $request->rating_id[$key]  to insert in database